# Hibernate does not accept ManyToOne as Id

Tags: java, hibernate, composite-key, many-to-one

Hibernate does not agree with this construction. Am I missing anything? The error it throws me:

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: version_id in processes

Any suggestions on how to fix while keeping the composite key structure?

**DataModel**

Version has many actions

Version has many processes;

```
public class Version {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int Id;
}
```

Action has one process

Action has one version

```
public class Action {
    // Action has a composite key (ID and Version ID)

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int id;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "version_id")
    public Version version;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "process_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "version_id", referencedColumnName = "version_id")
    })
    public Process process;
}
```

Process has many actions

Process has one version

```
    public class Process {
    // Process has a composite key (ID and Version ID)

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int id;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "version_id")
    public Version version;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "process", targetEntity = Action.class)
    public List<Action> actions= new ArrayList<Action>();
}
```

Picture of the model:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2294873/model.jpg

Comment: Specifying a `@Column` on a `@ManyToOne` is not allowed...

Comment: How do your tables look like?

Comment: Well, I let hibernate generate them... However, it doesn't because of this error...

Comment: I've added a picture of a part of the model of what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: You have two `JoinColumn` before Action.process. The second one doesn't need you.

Comment: Well, according to the model I do. The idea is that each version as a new incremental id of the process. Version 1, Process 1, 2,3; Version 2, Process 1, 2, 3.

Comment: You have two columns named version_id in Action class. Try renaming second version_id to process_version_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two columns named version_id in Action class. Try renaming second version_id to process_version_id:

```
public class Action {
    // Action has a composite key (ID and Version ID)

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int id;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "version_id")
    public Version version;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "process_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "process_version_id", referencedColumnName = "version_id")
    })
    public Process process;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed the problem. However: Hibernate cannot reuse a column for a different relation? So my plan just won't work. Is perfectly valid for me to reuse the version_id column in all these relations. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think not, because you could have two different versions in Action and Process. You can add that restriction when creating Action (i.e. check for versions before adding process into action).